# How to upload a new version on Magento Commerce

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, magento-connect

I hope some one knows more about the issue we are facing.
We have a extension that is uploaded on Magento commerce, and its a  paid version developed by us. Now we have developed a new version with more features and want to upload there. We know that there is a version feature available there on Magentocommerce admin.

We want to know that how the new version will be available for new users as well as is that new version will be available or notified to the old customers who brought previous version?

Is there any option on mangento ecommerce for choosing version so customers can by which one they want?

Comment: You mean choose which version to download?

Comment: Yes , how a user can choose, or is the older version will be replaced by newer one?

Comment: upload it separately or place a link in the description of existing module. Moreover for paid versions, users can't download from magento commerce they are redirected to your site.

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select an answer or add your own and "accept" it to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature in Magento Connect. See for example this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-credit-card-tokenization-extension.html) and in the Releases tab you will see you can download a previous version.

Comment: Thanks! @mbalparda, but can you guide me more?
If a user comes to any Free Magento Extension page like you have, and he try to install extension by main button of Extension, then which version of extension will be installed using Magento Connect?
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/57bo0/dhax

Comment: The latest version you uploaded will be installed in theory.